# Parse ${} placeholder into absolute path in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, properties

I have a app.properties file something like below

```
Base.dir="/user/test/application"
Result.dir="${base.dir}/result"
```

and i've create bash script to parse above properties

```
function readConfigFile()
{
  (grep -E "^${2}=" -m 1 "${1}" 2>/dev/null || echo "VAR=__UNDEFINED__") | head -n 1 | cut -d '=' -f 2-;
}

function setConfigFile()
{
    sourceFile=${1}
}

function configGet()
{
    if [ ! -z $sourceFile ]; then
        val="$(readConfigFile $sourceFile "${1}")";
        if [ "${val}" = "__UNDEFINED__" ]; then
            echo "${1} value not exist"
            # return empty string
            printf -- "%s" "";
        fi
        printf -- "%s" "${val}";
    else
        echo "config file not exist"
        # return empty string
        printf -- "%s" "";
    fi
}
```

and the way i call above parser is something like below

```
$Result_dir=$(configGet Result.dir)
```

however, i cant really translate placeholder ${} into base_dir

and i got following error

```
ls $Result_dir
ls: cannot access ${Base_dir}/result: No such file or directory
```

Is there any way that i can translate ${Base.dir} into /user/test/application?

Comment: As it's pointed out in the following answers, the problem is `.` in your property names. It seems it's a Java `.properties` file and you might not be able to change the naming scheme easily. Therefore, you have to preprocess your `app.properties` before feeding it to your `configGet`, e.g. `cat $1 | tr '.' '_' | grep -E ...` (which is less than ideal, given it won't work properly if you have `.` in your property values. An alternative is `sed`).

Comment: @HosseinPursultani right, it's java properties file
i'll give it try

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're not going to be able to substitute `${base.dir}` (btw shouldn't it be `${Base.dir}`?) the way you were hoping mainly because, as far as I know, dots are not allowed in variable names in bash.

What you could do is manually substitute the `${base.dir}` part with the corresponding path using bash's substitution syntax. For example:

```
setConfigFile 'app.properties'

Result_dir_raw=$(configGet Result.dir)
Result_dir=${Result_dir_raw/'${base.dir}'/$(configGet Base.dir)}

echo ${Result_dir}
```

I say "manually" because you still specify in your source code that the pattern you want to replace is `${base.dir}` which I'm guessing isn't what you wanted.

Now if you run this you'll see that the `${Result_dir}` variable evaluates to `""/user/test/application"/result"` which obviously isn't a path, and this is because you're surrounding the paths in `app.properties` with double quotes, so you either need to get rid of them in your `readConfigFile` function or lose them altogether in your config file, which to me makes more sense.

Comment: right, i also think it's gonna be hard to automatically substitute ${} placeholder
thanks for the solution

Answer (score 0):

Why have you a `.` in your variable name, which is not allowed in `bash`:

```
$ Base.dir="/user/test/application"
-bash: Base.dir=/user/test/application: No such file or directory
$ Base_dir="/user/test/application"
$
```

So, why do you get `No such file or directory`?  Here is an explanation:

Create a file called `Base.dir=gash.sh`, yes, that's a legal filename

```
$ echo 'echo Hello World' > Base.dir=gash.sh
```

Make the file executable:

```
$ PATH=$PATH:.
$ chmod u+x Base.dir=gash.sh
```

Now type the command:

```
$ Base.dir="gash.sh"
Hello World
```

Use an underscore, not a dot.  By the Way, `ksh` Korn shell not only allows the dot, it has a special meaning, it is a *compound variable*.

Comment: it's actually java properties file
and the way i convert it into bash variable by calling my parser method
Base_dir=$(configGet Base.dir)

Comment: It is your variable name causing the issue, not the file name.  Of course in Java the dot is an operator (for namespace traversal  and field access), so you are not allowed to have it as part of a variable name there either.